# Refresh DIV every x second without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There are many stackoverflow entries about div refresh. I tryed some codes but I dont get it to work.
In my DIV I want to call a php function (get current database entries). What should I change? Is it even possible to reload a div to make a new php function call?

my index_design.php:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"</script>

<body onload="startTime()">
   <div id="ajaxcontainer">
      <div>
         <?php $mycontroller->getEntries(); ?>
      </div>
      <div>
         <?php $mycontroller->getEntries2(); ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript_document_ready.js"></script>
```

my javascript_document_ready.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function loadlink(){
       $('#ajaxcontainer').load('index_design.php',function () {
          $(this).unwrap();
       });
    }

    loadlink(); 
    setInterval(function(){
       loadlink() 
    }, 10000);

}
```

Projectfolder:

- index_design.php
- Folder (JS) -> javascript.js
- Folder (JS) -> javascript_document_ready.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AJAX.

```
setInterval(_ => {
  $.ajax({
     url: "index_design.php",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "html",
     success: html => {
       $("#ajaxcontainer").html(html);
     }
  });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still cant get it to work with your code. Maybe there is another problem? But I cant find it.